# What am I missing in this Javascript Array behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I tried this in the chrome dev tools console:

```
let a = [[null,null],[null,null]]

function na(){ return Array(2).fill(Array(2)) }
let b = na();

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
// [[null,null],[null,null]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
// [[null,null],[null,null]]
```

So far, so good. I was expecting both *a* and *b* with the same values and strucuture. Then I wanted to test a small function that should append an extra value in each line:

```
function add(x) { x.map( line => line.push(null) )}

add(a)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
// [[null,null,null],[null,null,null]]

add(b)
console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
// [[null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null]]
// ?! I was not expecting this extra value here...
```

Well, that was unexpected.
Why is that extra *null* appearing in `add(b)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function na(){
    return Array(2).fill(Array(2))
}
```

`na()` fills the empty `Array(2)` with [`shallow copies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy) of the second `Array(2)` object.

As a result changing values in any of the clones changes the Array's value everywhere.

```js
a = Array(5).fill(Array(3))

a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[0][2] = 3

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

So because `b` has 2 elements and you are using `.push()` to add an element to `b` for each of the (same) arrays, 2 new elements are added to the array.

Comment: No, it does *not* create (shallow) copies of `Array(2)`